# Omit utility function, $Omit? Or short for $PropertyType?

Tags: flowtype

Lots of times I find myself using omit, which requires heavy use of `$PropertyType`

for instnace:

```
type EntityBase = {
    id: EntityId,
    created_at: DateStr
}

type Profile = {
    ...($Diff<EntityBase, {created_at:$PropertyType<EntityBase, 'created_at'>}>), // omit(created_at)
}
```

That's a lot of un-readable-ness for just trying to omit one key. Type of `Profile` is just an object of one key of `id`.

### Is there a `$Omit` and/or shortform for `$PropertyType`?

Here is how `$PropertyType` can turn into tons of typing:

```
type Props = {
    authorAvatar: $PropertyType<Profile, 'avatar'>,
    authorName: $PropertyType<Profile, 'name'>,
    commentsCnt: number,
    created_at: $PropertyType<StoryType, 'created_at'>,
    socialBoxId: $PropertyType<StoryType, 'socialBoxId'>,
    story_line: $PropertyType<StoryType, 'story_line'>,
    story_text: $PropertyType<StoryType, 'story_text'>
}
```

It would be awesome if can just do:

```
type Props = {
    authorAvatar: Profile.avatar,
    authorName: Profile.name,
    commentsCnt: number,
    created_at: StoryType.created_at,
    socialBoxId: StoryType.socialBoxId,
    story_line: StoryType.story_line,
    story_text: StoryType.story_text
}
```